# Python dict - some keys with the same value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to do a dictionary which include countries GMT time (int number)
for example I have a dict and I want to get the value of it, I tried this code:

```
countires= {('Jerusalem', 'Athens', 'Bucharest'):2 ,('Bahrain','Qatar'):3}
print(countires.get('Athens'))
```

and the output is:

```
None
```

How I can get result 2?

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what your dictionary looks like. You don't have a key `'Athens'`, you DO have a key `('Jerusalem', 'Athens', 'Bucharest')`

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, You need create temp `dict` that have seperate key and search what you want like below:

```
>>> countires= {('Jerusalem', 'Athens', 'Bucharest'):2 ,('Bahrain','Qatar'):3}

>>> dct = {k:value for key,value in countires.items() for k in key}

>>> print(dct.get('Athens'))
2
```

If you want to use your original `dictionary` you can define `function` and search in keys like below:

```
>>> def search_multi_key(search, dct):
...    for key, value in dct.items():
...        if search in key:
...            return value
...    return None
        
>>> search_multi_key('Athens', countires)
2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
both method will help me!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a new dictionary, that uses as key each of the elements of the tuples:

```
countries= {('Jerusalem', 'Athens', 'Bucharest'):2 , ('Bahrain', 'Qatar'):3}
cities = { key : value for keys, value in countries.items() for key in keys }
print(cities.get('Athens'))
```

**Output**

```
2
```